# index into a circular array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a circular array. I created it with the following:

```
from itertools import cycle
myArray = ['a','b','c','d']
pool = cycle(myArray)
```

Now I want to print the nth item in pool where n could be larger than 4. Normally this would be a simple use of the modulo function but logically I think Python has a method which will know the number of elements in the pool (`4` in this example) and automatically apply the modulo function.

For example the `1`st and `5`th item is `'a'`. So I'm hoping for, logically, the equivalent of `pool[0]` and `pool[4]` giving me `'a'`.

Is there such a method?

Comment: Wouldn't `myArray[n % 4]` achieve the same thing? (I guess I'm asking if you really need to pull lots of items out of the generator just to achieve something that could be done a simpler way.)

Comment: Mind that `pool` is not a circular array: it is a generator.

Comment: You're really not making any sense as to what you want.

Comment: Yes, I already said modulo could  be used. If you think I'm not making sense please read it more carefully. Everyone else made sense it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list is definitely the way to go but if you actually had a cycle object and wanted the nth object wrapping around, you could `islice`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
myArray = ['a','b','c','d']
pool = cycle(myArray)

print(next(islice(pool, 5)))
a
```

Note once you call `next(islice` you have started cycling the list, if you actually want to be constantly rotating you may actually want a `deque`

Comment: I think there is a difference between knowing the answer, and answering what you wanted to hear ;)

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no built-in method to accomplish what you're attempting to do.  As suggested earlier, you could use `zip`, but that would involve indexing into the result based on your sequence, as well as generating `n` elements out to the item you want.

Sometimes the simplest approach is the clearest.  Use modulo to accomplish what you're after.

```
def fetch_circular(n):
    myArray = ['a','b','c','d']
    return myArray[n % 4]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be confusing arrays with generators.

The modulo function of an array is the way to go, in terms of performance.

cycle is a function which generates elements as they are requested. It is not a Cycle class with convenient methods. You can see the equivalent implementation in the documentation, and you'll probably understand what is the idea behind it:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

Answer (score 0):

Your `pool` object is already a generator and it will keep looping through `myArray` forever, so all you need is to zip your iterator with `pool` this way:

```
>>> pool = cycle(myA)
>>> for i,item in zip(range(10),pool):
    print i,item


0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 a
5 b
6 c
7 d
8 a
9 b
>>>
```

Comment: A potential problem with this approach is that if you ask for the `10G`'th element, it will take some time whereas using the modulo approach, it is resolved in nanoseconds.